# Finding the index of the maximum value of the two vectors

Tags: c++

Good day everyone, I am trying to find the maximum element between two vectors and also want to find the index of this entry and in what vectors did it come from.

Suppose I got two vectors A and B,

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6 };

///// find the maximum value

int max = std::max(*std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end()), *std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end()));
std::cout << max;
```

How could I find the  index of this maximum value between two vectors and return which vector this come from?

Comment: `std::find()` + an appropriate return condition and value may be?

Comment: Instead of writing everything in a single line of code, start to use `if` statements, and use `std::distance` on the vector that contains the larger value.

Answer (score 3):

You already have most piece, just assemble them correctly:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6 };

///// find the maximum element of each vector
auto ita = std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end());
auto itb = std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end());

std::vector<int>* v; // pointer on the vector containing the max
std::size_t index; // index inside that vector

if (*ita > *itb) {
    index = std::distance(a.begin(), ita);
    v = &a;
} else {
    index = std::distance(b.begin(), itb);
    v = &b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::max_element` returns an *iterator* to the max element in the vector. You can use that iterator to get the index of that element.